# "CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)" does not show Bluetooth popup message when Bluetooth is turned off from Control Center

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am trying to navigate the user to **Bluetooth settings** on a button click. `CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)` works fine when Bluetooth is turned off from Settings App, **but it is not working when Bluetooth is turned off from Control center e.g not showing the default Bluetooth popup**.
Now I need to know if Bluetooth is turned off from the Control center so that I can show some custom popup message to the user.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the initialization option *CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey*, which should display a warning if the framework is initiated when bluetooth is turned off, does in fact not work as expected if bluetooth is toggled off from the Control Center. Since iOS 11 the system will actually **not** turn off bluetooth if you toggle off the button in Control Center, it only disconnects currently connected devices. The only way to turn off bluetooth then is to do it from System Settings. This is documented by Apple, but to me it is **extremely** misleading. So I honestly don't know if the API behavior you are experiencing is a bug, or if it is expected behavior.

My suggestion is that you skip this initialization option and instead rely on the value of *central.state* when you get the "*centralManagerDidUpdateState:*" callback and then create you own popup if the value is *CBManagerStatePoweredOff*, which oddly enough will be the case regardless if bluetooth is turned off from System Settings or if it is toggled off from the Control Center.

If your app works in the background you may want to use a local notification instead to get your user's attention.

Not a perfect solution, but it should be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have filed bug report 47516284 with Apple for this problem. Here's the text of the issue I filed.

I have noticed that the system alert notifying a user that an app needs Bluetooth will show when I turn off Bluetooth using the Settings app. I can use this system alert to go directly to bluetooth settings to turn it back on. However, when I turn off Bluetooth using Control center, there is no system alert that displays. This is problematic because although I can display a custom alert to tell the user to turn on Bluetooth, there is no way to code bringing the user directly to Bluetooth settings by tapping a button for instance. I believe the functionality should be consistent no matter how the user turns off Bluetooth.